# Functional react component vs React.Component when using propTypes

Tags: reactjs

React 0.14 introduced pure functions as components like this:

```
export const Label = ({title} => (
  <span>{label}</span>
)
```

However, I also want to describe to the component user which properties and types the component supports and which are the defaults.

So I have to add

```
Label.propTypes = {
  title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

Label.defaultProps = {
   title: "unknown"
}
```

I could also just use a `React.Component` like this:

```
class Label extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}
  static defaultProps = { 
    title: "unknown"
  }
  render() {
      <span>{this.props.label}</span>
  }
}
```

Everything would be instantly visible and the component understandable.

Why should we use functional components then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons I see to use functional components even in your case:

- No ES6 or React magic on component scale, so the output JS is much shorter.
- Cleaner separation. You have a function that return a presentational component. The "meta" data like default props are separated juste like ES6 components.
- As stated in the doc, React would like to provide special optimizations to functional components so it might be better performance-wise in the future to use them than regular components for presentation purposes :

> In an ideal world, most of your components would be stateless functions because in the future we’ll also be able to make performance optimizations specific to these components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory allocations. This is the recommended pattern, when possible.

Comment: Especially the optimization steps (code size and runtime speedup later) and cleaner code (no React magic) convinced me!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use the pure function components, the reason they were created was to facilitate the creation of stateless functional components without the need to extend the Component class. This article [stateless-components-in-react](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.e7hatu1oh) explains the point in details.